# SQL Server database Administration

Tags: sql-server, indexing

One of the tables having around 12 lacks (1.2 million) records and index size is very huge, around 123 Gb.

We have space crunch and the table has 4 indexes.

One is primary key clustered index and 3 XML indexes one primary XML and 2 secondary XML.

Is there any impact by dropping and creating indexes because once rebuild the index it will release some space to drive. Drive space is only 8 mb

Comment: Hi welcome to SO!. Please take some time to review your question and make it more clear and descriptive. Also you might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question suits better to the [dba website of the network](https://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: how are you fitting 123gb into 8mb .

Answer (score 0):

Re-Created Index should be no problem.

BTW, you'd better think about enhance the database, like partition it etc

and please put some comma between your sentence.